# Torque Disturbance Observer for Manipulator Arms

Tags: control, robotic-arm, torque

Is there a tutorial/guide apart from the research papers ( [paper 1](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-88513-9_3) and [paper 2](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/857974) ), for implementation of torque disturbance observers on multi-DOF robotic manipulators to determine sudden collision event or estimate feed-forward torque.